# Printing what number Pari/GP is working on for a parallel computation

Tags: pari-gp

I am using Pari/GP to test (pseudo)primality of a sequence of numbers `f(n)`, where `f(n)` is some function. I have parallelized the code as

```
test(a) = parfor(n = 1, +oo, if(ispseudoprime(f(n)), print("PRIME "n));)
```

This works very well but I would also like to know which number is being tested. I can of course just add `print(n)` after the `if`. The problem is that `ispseudoprime(a(n))` can take quite some time for `n` while being very fast for `n+1`. Since the computation is parallel, the output would quickly becomes a mess: I would see the list of numbers that have been tested, but I have no indication of what number is being tested at a given moment (the idea is that if the program is spending a lot of time on a number it is more and more likely to be prime, so I would like to know it).

Is there a simple way of doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved (in a very dirty way probably) like this

```
test(a) = parfor(n = 1, +oo, write("started",n); if(ispseudoprime(f(n)), print("PRIME "n)); write("done",n))
```

Then `grep -v -f done started` gives what I want.